# Python: Improve this by making the algorithm less complex

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a working block of code, but it seems there should be a more efficient algorithm, presumably with less loops or using a library/module.

This example version of the code takes a list of strings, reverse sort by `len()`, then build a new list:

```py
gs = ["catan", "ticket to ride", "azul"]

mg = {}
for i in range(len(gs)):
        mg[i] = len(gs[i])

popularity = {k: v for k, v in sorted(mg.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
tg = []
for game in popularity.keys():
        tg.append(gs[game])
```

The production code does not set `mg[i]` to `len()` and the elements in the list are not necessarily strings, but the algorithm works otherwise.

For this, the same output is:

```
['ticket to ride', 'catan', 'azul']
```

**How can I improve the efficiency of this algorithm?**

Comment: What is it supposed to _do_ in the end?

Comment: Sort the list by the criteria largest number to smallest number. In this example the number is len(mg[i]). I'll add sample output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gs = ["catan", "ticket to ride", "azul"]
tg = sorted(gs, key=len, reverse=True)
```

has the same effect for a list of strings.

If you want to sort the list in place for more space efficiency,

```
gs.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

This also works for a custom "criteria function":

```
def my_criteria_function(value):
    return len(value) * value.count(" ")  # super secret sauce

...sort(key=my_criteria_function) # (or sorted(..., key=my_criteria_function)
```

Comment: len is the same code, production doesn't use len()

Comment: It doesn't matter; substitute that function for `len` then.

Comment: Confirmed in production. Thanks.